# Airflow - xcom returns the value with comma in the last

Tags: python, airflow

I just tried the xcom pull to print the return value of a task.

Basically, I ran a SQL task `select 123123123` it will return `123123123`. And my dag is,

```py
<<args and DAG details goes here>>

def puller(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    pulled_value_1 = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_result')
    print("VALUE IN PULLER : ", pulled_value_1)

def get_dag_ids(**kwargs):
    postgres_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='cloudsqlpg')
    records = postgres_hook.get_records(sql='select 123123123')
    return records

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="push_result",
    python_callable=get_dag_ids,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)

pull = PythonOperator(
    task_id='pullee',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=puller,
    provide_context=True,
)


t1 >> pull
```

I got the output from the task t1 as below.

```
INFO - Done. Returned value was: [(123123123,)]
```

I just need the correct value as **123123123**. Is it an array? how do I extract the correct value from this result?

Comment: Throwing a hail mary: have you tried `return records[0][0]`?

Comment: It worked, thanks, can you please help me to understand this command `records[0][0]`?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to unpack it into a single list/tuple.
[123123123..., n]

```
list(itertools.chain(*records)) 

tuple(itertools.chain(*records))
```

Then it'll be easier to access each result i.e records[0]